# Setting up a Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian

I have just started trying to set up my new Raspberry Pi. I have installed NOOBS and it is now asking which operating system I would like to use. It is recommending 'raspbian'. could anybody tell me why raspbian is the best one to use?

Comment: Please keep these questions over at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/ they are off topic for SO

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raspbian is perfect for beginners to the raspberry pi.

- It is easy to set-up and use
- There is lots of support available on-line for it, as most people are using it.
- It is based on Debian which is a widley used OS.
- It is specifically designed to run on the raspberry pi.

However it all depends on what you want to use your Pi for, raspbian is great for general use. But if you were looking to do something more specific, like set up a media centre you might want to use [RaspBMC](http://www.raspbmc.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Just to amplify Matthew's view, you'll also find most of the standard starter's printed documentation assumes Raspbian. You will also be amazed how easy it is to get the Pi going, getting network and internet connectivity and starting off with the applications built in.

For such as very very basic system, Pi/Raspbian does an awful lot for minimal effort.

Answer (score -1):

You could do what I did and install NOOBS it comes preloaded with python 3, python 2, scratch, and a bunch more.(plus Raspbian).

Comment: … the question starts by installing NOOBS.